# Constructive argument for showing that a continuous unbounded function $f:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty), f(0)=0,$ attains all values on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a continuous monotonically increasing unbounded function such that $f(0) = 0$. What would be a clean constructive argument for showing that $f$ attains every value on $[0, \infty)$, that is that for any $y \in [0, \infty)$ there exists $x\in [0, \infty)$ such that $f(x) = y$? If you are willing to play with a proof by contradiction, you could use unboundedness of $f$ and the fact that a continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets. Therefore taking a wide enough interval $[0, a]\subset [0,\infty)$ ensures that $y \in f([0, a])$. But I would like hear a constructive argument for this. Thanks!

Comment: My first instinct would be to see what there is to learn about constructive versions of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: If you were given some positive "lower bound on the derivative of $f$" or something similar, then that should allow you to construct an algorithm to find $x$ given $y$.  Otherwise, if for example you're allowing functions which remain constant on some interval, my guess would be that you could come up with an adversarial function which adjusts the value of a constant (or near constant) part of a function just below or above $y$ to force either the guess of just below that part or just above that part to be incorrect, showing a constructive algorithm can't exist.

Comment: My guess. What would be your constructive definition of "$f$ is (upper) unbounded"? It may be "there is an algorithm $g$ such that $\forall N, f(g(N)) > N$. Then $\forall N>0$, we can apply a dichotomy algorithm, beginning on $[0, g(N)]$, that converges to an $x$ such that $f(x)=N$.

Comment: How constructive do you have in mind? For instance letting $x:=\sup\{ z\in [0,\infty): f(z)<y\}$ gives you such a point.

Comment: @Jose27 I think this will do as well as Martin's suggestion. Thanks!